# Render table subheader only once in React

Tags: reactjs

I have created the following table in React.

The items I render have either category `libraries` or `softwareComponents` as category.

```
{
  items.map((component: Components) =>
    component.category === "libraries" ? (
      <React.Fragment>
        <tr>
          <th>Libraries</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <tr key={component.name}>
          <td>{component.name}</td>
          <td>{component.version}</td>
        </tr>
      </React.Fragment>
    ) : (
      <React.Fragment>
        <tr>
          <th>Software Components</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <tr key={component.name}>
          <td>{component.name}</td>
          <td>{component.version}</td>
        </tr>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  );
}
```

The problem is that the subheader is rendered now every time but I only want to show it once.

[image]

Comment: could you add your items list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can separate item list and write like this :

```js
const libraryList = items.filter((item) => item.category === "libraries");
const others = items.filter((item) => item.category !== "libraries");

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {libraryList.length && (
        <>
          <tr>
            <th>Libraries</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
          </tr>
          {libraryList.map((component) => (
            <tr key={component.name}>
              <td>{component.name}</td>
              <td>{component.version}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
      {others.length && (
        <>
          <tr>
            <th>Software Components</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
          </tr>
          {others.map((component) => (
            <tr key={component.name}>
              <td>{component.name}</td>
              <td>{component.version}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare two arrays, one for `libraries` and one for `software`. Then, you map the `items` outside of the return statement and push each table row to the matching array.

And after that you simply return the arrays in the return statement. See [codeSandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bsvxhn?file=src%2FApp.js)

```
const libraries = [];
const software = [];

items.map((component) => {
    const tableRow = (
      <tr key={component.name}>
        <td>{component.name}</td>
        <td>{component.version}</td>
      </tr>
    );
    component.category === "libraries"
      ? libraries.push(tableRow)
      : software.push(tableRow);
  });
```

And your JSX:

```
return (
    <>
      <tr>
        <th>Libraries</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
      {libraries}
      <tr>
        <th>Software Components</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
      {software}
    </>
  );
```